# Freebsd 8.1 Samba4 smbclient returns NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: raid, samba, freebsd, network-attached-storage, samba4

I'd like to setting up a NAS server and run Samba4 on it.
When I'm runing this command:

```
# smbclient -I 192.168.48.128 -L NAS_GROUP
Enter root's password:
Connection to 192.168.48.128 failed (Error NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)
```

Here is my /usr/local/etc/smb4.conf :

```
[global]

workgroup = NAS_GROUP
server string = nas_server
security = user
interfaces = em0
log file = /var/log/samaba/log.%m
max log size = 50
local master = no
dns proxy = no
unix charset = UTF-8
dos charset = cp850

#Partages :
[documents]
comment = documents dir
path = storage/documents
wirteable = yes
hide dot files = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = %S

[medias]
comment = medias dir
path = storage/medias
wirteable = yes
hide dot files = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = %S
```

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check path and writeable lines.
path must be an absolute path
and writeable shouldn 't be wirteable